# Pipx created binary errors out: `module not found`

Tags: python-3.x, pip, command-line-interface, pipx

I have a multi-file system which all depend on each other. An example is this `import get_all_files as file_system` in the `main.py` file.

#### Setups followed

1. Create a `setup.py` with the configurations

```py
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='name',
    version='1.0.0',
    author='etc etc',
    author_email='etc etc',
    description='A tool etc etc',
    packages=['src'],
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'eclair = src.main:process_arguments',
        ],
    },
    install_requires=[
        'jinja2',
        'web3',
    ],
)
```

2. `python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel`
3. `pipx install dist/<name-version-etc>.tar.gz # installs correctly`
4. 

#### Error

```bash
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/homebrew/bin/tool-name", line 5, in <module>
    from src.main import process_arguments
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/src/main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import get_all_files as file_system
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'get_all_files'
```

I'm wondering where the error is as using VS Code's Pylint, I am able to ensure none of these errors are occuring outside of this build.

Comment: what are you expecting to get ?